# pass option to npm script to just compile specific folder babel

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using the babel cli to compile es6 to es5

My package.json looks like this

```
"scripts":{
  "build": "node ./scripts/generate.js && babel src -d es5 --copy-files"
}
```

I would like to be able to pass an option so that babel only compiles a certain folder. Currently it compiles everything in `src` and copies the output to an es5 folder.

Would it be possible to do something like

`npm run build -folder-option=ExampleFolder`

If there is anything unclear in my question please let me know.

Comment: you can do it using webpack

Comment: thanks @goor ok, do you have any ideas how?

Comment: give me few min i will show you an example

Answer (score 0):

make sure you `npm install webpack` before.
the simplest way to configure a webpack config with babel:

```
 var path = require('path');
 var webpack = require('webpack');

 module.exports = {
     entry: './js/app.js',
     output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
         filename: 'bundle.js'// export file
     },
     module: {
         loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.js$/, //file with this ending will transpile by babel
                 include: [
                   path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
                  ],
                 exclude: '/node_modules/', // ignore node_modules folder
                 loader: 'babel-loader',
                 query: {
                     presets: ['es2015']
                 }
             }
         ]
     },
     devtool: 'source-map' // for the chrome debugger
 };
```